# Python 3, sort list . highest value

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to sort a simple highscore list.
I want it to sort on score. Highest first.

```
from operator import itemgetter
dic = []
for stuff in range(3):
  name = input("Name:")
  score = input("Score:")
  result = (name,score)
  dic.append(result)

sort1 = sorted(dic, key=lambda score: score[1])
print(sort1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out why it didn't work.
It took score as a string and I needed to convert it to int.
And reverse sorting .

```
sort1 = sorted(dic, key=lambda score: int(score[1]),reverse=True)
```